# Cannot add elements of arrays using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to add elements of two arrays and store them in a third array. I'm experimenting with pointers so I want to use them as arguments to the user defined function.
When, I run the code, I get the Error: **exited, segmentation fault**, as soon as I enter the first two values for the array.
I am painfully unaware of what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

float addarrays(float ptra1[5], float ptra2[5], float ptra3[5])
{
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        ptra3[i] = ptra1[i] + ptra2[i];
    }
  return *ptra3;
}

int main()
{
    float A[5], B[5], C[5];
    float *ptA[5], *ptB[5], *ptC[5];
    
    cout<<"Enter Array A: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Element A["<< i <<"] = ";
        cin>>*ptA[i];
    }
    
    cout<<"\nEnter Array B: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Element B["<< i <<"] = ";
        cin>>*ptB[i];
    }
    
    addarrays(*ptA, *ptB, *ptC);
    cout<<"Displaying result for C[i] = A[i] + B[i]: \n";
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout<<"\nElement C["<< i <<"] = "<<*ptC[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use arrays.  Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: you are trying store values without allocating memory for it. Just before your `cin>>*ptX[i];` write `ptX[i]=&X[i];`  ex `ptA[i]=&A[i];` . Also use another loop to set `ptC[i]=&C[i]`. But all that is overkill, you can directly use pointers referring to array.

Comment: *"as soon as I enter the first two values for the array"* -- this gives you a way to trim down your [mre]. Since you never get to the line `cout<<"\nEnter Array B: \n"`, remove it and all following lines down to the end of your `main` function. Then remove the now-unused declarations and definitions. You'll have a much more focused question, with fewer red herrings.

Answer (score 0):

For starters these arrays of pointers

```
float *ptA[5], *ptB[5], *ptC[5];
```

are not initialized.

So this statement

```
cin>>*ptA[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior.

You could set elements of the array `ptA` for example in a loop like

```
size_t i = 0;
for ( auto &p : ptA ) p = A + i++;
```

Pay attention to that the function `addarrays` does not set elements of the array `ptC`. In fact it tries to ser elements of the array `C` provided that the array `ptC` was correctly initialized. Array `ptC` is still uninitialized. So this statement

```
cout<<"\nElement C["<< i <<"] = "<<*ptC[i];
```

again will invoke undefined bejavior.

Thus you need to initialize the arrays of pointers.

```
size_t i = 0;
for ( auto &p :ptA ) p = A + i++;

i = 0;
for ( auto &p :ptB ) p = B + i++;

i = 0;
for ( auto &p :ptC ) p = C + i++;
```

The function can be declared and defined the following way

```
void addarrays(float * ptra1[], float * ptra2[], float * ptra3[], size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        *ptra3[i] = *ptra1[i] + *ptra2[i];
    }
}
```

and called like

```
addarrays( ptA, ptB, ptC, 5 );
```